# SSH Clients which suppport click to copy and right click to paste in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I am using Remmina and it seems to be "okay". I am trying to find a client which can help a bit more, copy on click and paste on right click functions like mremote.

What are folks with ubuntu using for this ?

Comment: For decades, the standard behavior in the unix world has been highlight to copy and *middle* click to paste, is there a reason that doesn't work for you?

Comment: Thank you drewbenn and 0xSheepdog for response. After posting i did further lookup and was able to find a decent client "Termius". 

Appreciate your suggestions though!

Comment: My client-of-choice when forced to work from a local Windows system is [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/), but I really prefer to stay on Linux/Unix platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install an app which looks neat and allows click and copy capabilities as i needed.

For those who may be interested, i used `snap install termius-app`